# Two fixed scrollable left sidebar divs work in simple html, but not in rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have two scrollable fixed left sidebar divs:
https://jsfiddle.net/4654eaue/13/

```css
.category {   
    position: fixed;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    
  }
  .sub-category {  
    position: fixed;
    top:250px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    z-index:1;
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="small-2 columns category left-sidebar">
        <ul>
          <li>some list items</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="small-2 columns sub-category left-sidebar">
        <ul>
          <li>some list items</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

So this code works as expected. But in is not working in rails app.
I just put the code inside the partial, and render it in my pages.
What can cause this problem?

Comment: There isn't anything magical about being in a rails app, so it should still work. Are the styles being loaded properly once you put it into rails? It's hard to tell with what you have

Comment: @WesFoster, inspecting in browser showed that my styles are loaded properly and are not occasionally overwritten

Comment: Good to know. So how is it behaving? Obviously not as expected, but what is it doing?

Comment: @WesFoster, it is just fixed, overflowed content is hidden.